# Get a std::function into a new thread created by a c-api i.e. windows scm

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, winapi, service

### Background (To hopefully avoid a XY-Question:)

To refactor my C++ code handling the windows service manager, I'm trying to write a portable c++ service library including windows service manager.

So I thought the most comfortable, but simple approach would offer the user, to deliver his/her root functions, which reassembles the actual service, as a `std::function<void(void)>`, thus additional user defined parameters could be added via lambdas or `std::bind`.

### Precondition

These user defined functions, will often have to start in new threads (like in the windows scm).

**Problem is:** old C-APIs like many service frameworks, i.e. the windows service framework, makes it impossible to pass the function of the new thread any arguments. (yes often `*void` is allowed but would AFAIK imply lifetime problems and the windows framework doesn't allow even that.)

### Question

So how do I get this `std::function`(s) into a new thread(s), without using passed arguments?

I thought of maybe using a static `std::map<id,std::function<>>` but I don't know what to use as the id.

Comment: if you can give an example of the OS api call's signature I can probably help you. you're saying it takes a function pointer and a void*?

Comment: No at least the windows service framework (`StartServiceCtrlDispatcher`) won't take anything, it's just taking a function pointer, of type `LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION`, which in return defines a function accepting a char array like main, but thanks to the "genius" of the api design, the content of this char array can't be set by the user. It's suppose to get the arguments to the program, but only in special cases, otherwise, main() get's them.

Comment: since there's only one service implementation per executable, can't you just store state data in a static object?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like I have to drop the functionality of adding multiple root functions. Although

Comment: The map key could be as simple as a unique number that you increment every time you start a thread; then just pass the key to the thread so that it knows what map member to look up.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Did you read the question? How can I pass it to the thread?